# Where can I get stats on mouse clicks?

Tags: statistics

I'm interested in finding out whether people tend to click the mouse faster when it's cold or hot, if the time of day affects the speed of mouse clicks, and lots of other information like that.

Does anyone know where I can get this kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get at least some of this kind of information on Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows with WhatPulse:

https://whatpulse.org

As far as combining that with other data like time of day or cold or hotness, I would check out AppleEvents and possibly using a USB micro controller to measure the temperature and keep track of time of day... you could even make a USB-based micro controller that hooks up between the mouse and the keyboard and collects mouse clicks and passes them along, keeping track of those other data points along the way. If you have any questions about how to get/use/program a micro controller, shoot me a message!

Aha! I found something for you:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161752/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter2/altermouse/)

Comment: I'm looking into AppleEvents right now. Thanks a lot for the info you've given me. My only question is, is there a way to check people's clicks within the hour or something? Or see how fast they can click within a time frame and not just the total amount of clicks on WhatPulse.org?

Comment: You might be interested in Apple's technical documentation on handling mouse events at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html  As far as I skimmed over it, it seems like you could only really capture clicks within your own app, not globally throughout the system, which is what I would assume you want to do. Someone did actually make an app that records all mouse clicks and keyboard strokes at https://www.jitbit.com/mac-mouse-recorder/ if you're interested.

Comment: Scratch the AppleEvents - I don't think you can do anything with mouse clicks in AppleEvents - but they are used for other events and is part of the basis of the AppleScript language. Like moving files and folders, interacting with apps, etc.